# Karate - convert JSON string field to JSON Object

Tags: karate

I have an API that returns an JSON array of objects, where one of fields contains escaped JSON. Let's say it looks like that:

```
{
  "results":[
    {
      "id": "id-1",
      "data": "{\"name\", \"Adam\", \"surname\": \"Parker\"}"
    },
    {
      "id": "id-2",
      "data": "{\"name\", \"Adam\", \"surname\": \"Parker-Bates\"}"
    },
    {
      "id": "id-3",
      "data": "{\"name\", \"Adam Robert\", \"surname\": \"Parker\"}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Now,  I need to assert that that array contains exactly one element matching given criteria, let's say I'm looking for `Adam Parker`. If it would be returned as a proper JSON object it would be pretty straightforward. I could search for substrings, but it can give me false results. Maybe I could look for certain regular expressions to match only `\"Adam\"` and `"\Parker\"` but would prefer to convert that strings to JSON objects, since real case scenario has much more complex, nested data. Is there any way to do it with karate? I do not need ids, so I can extract data to array of strings if that would make it easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's easy, Karate has a few helper functions hanging off the `karate` JS object: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#the-karate-object

By the way your JSON is not well-formed (comma instead of colon) which got me stuck for a while.

Here's a demo, also refer the documentation on how to do JSON transforms, we are using JS array methods below: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#json-transforms

```
* def response =
"""
{
  "results":[
    {
      "id": "id-1",
      "data": "{\"name\": \"Adam\", \"surname\": \"Parker\"}"
    },
    {
      "id": "id-2",
      "data": "{\"name\": \"Adam\", \"surname\": \"Parker-Bates\"}"
    },
    {
      "id": "id-3",
      "data": "{\"name\": \"Adam Robert\", \"surname\": \"Parker\"}"
    }
  ]
}
"""
* def names = response.results.map(x => karate.fromString(x.data))
* match names contains { name: 'Adam', surname: 'Parker' }
```