# Unable to fetch the value in Karate API

Tags: automation, karate

How can I fetch the value of `StreetNumber` from the below response using Karate API print function?

```
"data": {
    
    "value": "{\"StreetNumber\":\"55\",\"PostalCode\":\"A1A1B1\",\"Language\":\"English\"
    
  }
}
```

I tried :

- `print response.data.value.StreetNumber` but it is not not fetching the correct value which is 55. It's not printing anything. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That's not valid JSON. You may need to do a [conversion](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#type-conversion). Here is an example (because you pasted something incomplete).

```
* def response = { "data": "{\"some\":\"more\"}" }
* json data = response.data
# this will also work
# def data = karate.fromString(response.data)
* def some = data.some
* match some == 'more'
```

Similar answer for reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407361/143475

Comment: This is the response postman gave when I did the GET request. And, I am unable to do the conversion.

Comment: @RiaBansal sorry I can't help any more. try to improve your question and someone else may help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask